# nuvola player installation problems 13.10

Tags: installation, package-management, ppa, repository, 13.10

So I'm trying to install nuvola player on my laptop running ubuntu 13.10.

I follow the instructions on their website. Pretty standard, add the repo, apt-get update, and then install. However, no matter how many times I add the PPA ubuntu can't find the package. These are the commands I run.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nuvola-player-builders/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nuvolaplayer
```

I get a "unable to locate package nuvolaplayer" message.

I know that is needs a new maintainer, but the ppa should still be active right?

anyway, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packages for Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander) are available only in the Nuvola Player Unstable Builds PPA. I haven't tested any version of Nuvola Player on Ubuntu 13.10, so I don't dare to put "stable" label on them.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nuvola-player-builders/unstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nuvolaplayer
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe nuvola player is no longer supported, had the same trouble getting from the repository. You can download the source and install manually from here. http://nuvolaplayer.fenryxo.cz/download.html 
Hopefully will get pick up again soon :)